# Are Excel functions reevaluated when their cells are referenced by other functions?

Tags: excel-formula

For example, let's say we have a cell A1 with `=SEARCH("h", "hello")`, which would obviously return 1. Suppose we make another cell B1 with `=INDEX(C1:D100, 1, A1)`.

Would the formula in B1 reevaluate the formula in A1? In other words, would the formula in B1 evaluate as `=INDEX(C1:D100, 1, 1)` or `=INDEX(C1:D100, 1, SEARCH("h", "hello"))`?

This may seem like a trivial question, but the examples are an extreme simplification; in my workbook, I'm searching for text across an entire sheet, whose results I use to feed a few thousand `INDEX` formulas in another sheet. And I'm worried about performance issues if every single cell is going to reevaluate the searches for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is optimised to recalculate only when required.

See Charles Williams' article about [Excel's smart recalculation](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecrets.htm) for details.

In short, a formula is only recalculated if any of its precedents change. Let's change your example in cell A1 to `=countif(B:B,A2)`.

The index function takes the output of A1 without re-running the countif. But, if a value in column B changes, or if the value in A2 changes, the countif will recalculate and after that the Index will recalculate.